# Java - How to make this algorithm correction, where i do not know when value0 and value1 is not empty and null

Tags: java

How to make this algorithm better and working, where I am always ending up to `reallyFail();`. And I cannot let it in while loop for an unlimited amount of time, only for 5 minutes at most.

```
// This is a heavy rendering encryption which takes sometimes 1 minute 
// or sometimes
// it takes less then 1 seconds, very random to estimate to a fix time or delay
prepareEncoding(letter);

// Now once that is done i have two values which if null or empty 
// Goal can not be accomplished
if (main.myencryption0 != null && main.myencryption1 != null) {
  // Once those value are available
  // Proceed to he Goal
  prepareToGoal(letter);
} else {

  // Value is empty or null we do not know the status
  // We try for 3 times the same thing 
  // (i think this is wrong, but could not find alternative best way)
  for (int i = 0; main.myencryption0 == null && main.myencryption1 == null && i <= 3; ++i) {
    prepareEncoding(letter); 
  }

  // Wait still for few seconds to make 100% sure
  // We can not wait more then 5 minute, because its too long.
  try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }  

  // Finally again check same thing do or die
  if (main.myencryption0 != null && main.myencryption1 != null) {
    prepareToGoal(letter);
  } else {
    reallyFail(); // OK - give up, drop the ball
  }

}
```

Comment: Not really sure what's going on here. If you're waiting for a thread to finish, why not just wait for the thread to finish instead of guessing times?

Comment: I think it suits better for [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think we need to see what `prepareEncoding` does to be able to help.

Comment: Are main.myencryption0 and its friend changed by prepareEncoding()? If not you can move the checking of them to outside the for loop (e.g. put the in an if statement which checks them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the time with System.currentTimeMillis. So you can leave the while after 5 min.

```
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 300000; //After 5 min leave while loop

while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime 
  && main.myencryption0 == null
  && main.myencryption1 == null)
{
  prepareEncoding(letter); 

  try {
    Thread.sleep(1);
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }  
}

if (main.myencryption0 != null && main.myencryption1 != null) {
  prepareToGoal(letter);
} else {
  reallyFail(); // OK - give up, drop the ball
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked in java in a while, so I don't know the exact language constructs, but try something like this:

```
// declare how long you are willing to wait
int maxWait = 5;   // assuming in minutes

// do your prepare goal stuff here
// ...
// ...

// get the time I started
Time started = new Time();   // use the proper construct here to get the current time
Time now;

// keep trying for some amount of time
while(!(main.myencryption0 != null && main.myencryption1 != null))
{
    // wait some arbitrary amount of time
    try { Thread.Sleep(1); }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.PrintStackTrace(); }

    // too long?
    now = new Time();  // again, get what time it is right now
    if (now > started.AddMinutes(maxWait))
        break;
}

// Finally again check same thing do or die
if (main.myencryption0 != null && main.myencryption1 != null)
    prepareToGoal(letter);
else
    reallyFail(); // OK - give up, drop the ball
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, looks like you are working on single Thread. Thread.sleep(3000) just wastes 5 minutes doing nothing.

Look at his example - [Interrupt thread after specified time - problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197542/interrupt-thread-after-specified-time-problems)